# Android: Changing Visibility of an item inside all listview rows

Tags: android, android-listview, visibility, android-imageview

I have a ListView in my application which can, after user requests it, be re-arrangeable via the drag of an imageview at the start of each listview's row. I present the user with the listview in a small window, and in order to maximize the space, I set the visibility of the drag view as GONE, and plan on only setting it to Visible when user selects a menu item that calls for Edit List Items.

Here's the layout for a row item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/drag_handle"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_drag_dots_holo_dark" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drag_n_drop_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minHeight="24dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for the menu selection:

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_edit_playlist:
        if (inEditMode) {
            //If we are already showing the drag view, hide it. 
            inEditMode = false;                             
            findViewById(R.id.drag_handle).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            //If the drag view is hidden, make it visible. 
            inEditMode = true;
            findViewById(R.id.drag_handle).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }                       
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code, is that when I call `setVisibility()` it only changes the visibility of the drag view on the firstmost item of the listview, and the dragview on all other rows remains hidden.

What would I do to make ALL dragViews on all rows visible in this case?

**EDIT**
Here's an [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64bucsxrgw8stks/Screenshot_2013-02-14-06-18-57.png) of how I want it to look after pressing edit, and here's an [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kurlq0m4o6wz2l/Screenshot_2013-02-14-06-21-47.png) of how it looks right now, with the code above.

Thanks!

Comment: 1 picture is better than thusands of words.

Comment: @hakiko I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to imply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem with this code, is that when I call setVisibility() it
>   only changes the visibility of the drag view on the firstmost item of
>   the listview, and the dragview on all other rows remains hidden.

That behavior it's normal as you're trying to change the visibility of a `View` from a row using `findViewById()`, method which will return the **first** occurrence of a `View` with that id from the layout. That first occurrence will be the situated in the first visible row of the list(anyway the `findViewById` method will not work, as you can probably see the views in the `ListView`'s rows will all have the same ids).

> What would I do to make ALL dragViews on all rows visible in this
>   case?

The proper way is to let the adapter of the `ListView` know in which state it's currently in(*inEditMode*) and show/hide the drag handle in the `getView` method based on that. Once you do this all you have to do in the `onContextItemSelected` is to update the `inEditMode` state variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the adapter.

Comment: can you provide an example please. i am facing the same issue

Comment: @Nikita I don't know what example to give you(about what part of the). You just need to maintain a boolean value to indicate the current state and update the adapter.